# How to disable vertical scrolling of a view in android?

Tags: android

In my android application.I have a panorama view, in this view i want to avoid only vertical scrolling. So i disabled  it using  `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method.

Hear is the code.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if( event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent:ACTION_UP");
        return false;
    }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent:ACTION_DOWN");     
        return false;
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent:ACTION_UNKWON");
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

but it disables scrolling horizontally also.How can i solve this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the notion of `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`.

`ACTION_DOWN` means when your finger touches the touchscreen, `ACTION_UP` is when you lift your finger from the touchscreen.

That said, you can indicate in `ACTION_DOWN` that the motion event started, check in `ACTION_MOVE` the direction of the touch event from the coordinates and decide whether you want to block the movement or not, and reset your variables in `ACTION_UP`.

```
float startX
float startY;   

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        startX = event.getX();
        startY = event.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float currentX = event.getX();
        float currentY = event.getY();

        float diffX = Math.abs(currentX - startX);
        float diffY = Math.abs(currentY - startY);

        // The purpose of the +100 is to make sure that we have a big enough
        // difference between the 2 directions, eg. it's not diagonal
        if(diffY > diffX + 100){
            return false;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: yeah Paradx i misunderstood the notation.i tried with your code its working thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this should work for a panorama view, but for other views I used a GestureDetector to catch the scroll/fling movements (I usually use fling since scroll is a very short movement):

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY){
   if (Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX))
    return true;// mark the vertical scroll as handled and do nothing
   return false;
}
```

The other option would be to use onTouchEvent, but then in ACTION_MOVE you have to detect when you have a vertical scroll (as paradx said).

Hope it helps:)